# AttributeError at /cart 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

in django e-commerce website i have the error

> AttributeError at /cart 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

i'm realy dont what happend, i have the code which must work with my task, but it doesnt work too
Please help me
U can find a code below

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Category, Product, Cart, CartItem
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


# Create your views here.
def _cart_id(request):
    cart = request.session.session_key
    if not cart:
        cart = request.session.create()
    return cart


def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            cart_item.quantity += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(product=product, quantity=1, cart=cart)
        cart_item.save()

    return redirect('cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items=None):
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, active=True)
        for cart_item in cart_items:
            total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
            counter += cart_item.quantity

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request, 'cart.html', dict(cart_items=cart_items, total=total, counter=counter))
```

Comment: Share the full traceback...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.